# Header background image changes size when width of page changes

Tags: html, css

my header background image changes size when I change the width of my browser, to the point that if the width gets small enough, my image will get pushed out. I have `background-size: 120%;` and I know that's what's causing it. Would there be a way to set the minimal size of the background image via percentage? If not, how could I fix this?

You can vist my website at [erraticfox.tumblr.com](http://erraticfox.tumblr.com) if needed a example of the problem.

Oh and here's my headers CSS code:

```css
#header {
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 800px;
    background: url('https://dm2013.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/img/background.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: 0px -650px;
    background-size: 110%;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle, you might want to resize the width of the result window and you'll see my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/2AbKb/

Comment: It would be better if you can reproduce the problem at http://jsfiddle.net so people can tweak and test and post the result.

Comment: You can tweak and test the live site. :-)

Comment: you can set the minimum width of the image using css "min-width" property. It will retain minimum width on resizing.

Comment: @Diffy, I am using mid-width... It does it for the header, but not the image.

Answer (score 2):

Its not resizing here. I have removed 'display-table' as i dont think it was necessary.

**HTML**

```
<div id="hed">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#hed{


    margin: auto;


    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 800px;
    background: url('https://dm2013.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/img/background.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position: 0px -650px
    background-size: 110%;
 background-color:black;


}
```

Comment: I fixed it, all I had to do was set `background-size` to cover instead of 110%, thank you though.

Comment: nice bro @Diffy  +1  for `background-attachment:fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
#header {
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  height: 300px;
  min-width: 800px;
  background: url('https://dm2013.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/img/background.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Well, I'm trying to keep it on how it looks, but just make it so the background doesn't shrink all the way up at a small width.

Answer (score 0):

Lose `background-attachment:fixed;` Is that the effect you're after?

Comment: No, I want the background to scroll with the page whilst the header stays at the top.

Comment: Do you have access to an image editor? Crop the image and make it the size you want.

Comment: @Jeroen, it does provide an answer to the problem, it's just not one the OP wants.

Comment: @slynagh, you are right. Honest mistake on my part!